# Quarkus integration tests coverage in gradle

Tags: integration-testing, quarkus

The Quarkus [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/tests-with-coverage#coverage-for-integration-tests) explains how to generate a correct jacoco coverage report for the integration tests. The documentation covers the maven setup, but not the gradle one. I tried to find something on internet but with no luck, anyone knows how to do it?

Marco

Comment: I am not much of a Gradle user, so if you figure this out we would love to receive a contribution for what you ask :)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [Quarkus guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/tests-with-coverage#coverage-for-tests-not-using-quarkustest) and below code works for me. I have added the comments as well.
Please note that quarkus-jacoco extension creates one execution file for both unit and integration test coverage. So you need to pass the path of the jacoco report (`$build/jacoco-report/jacoco.xml`) to sonar via (`sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths`) argument.

Note - Make sure you add `quarkus.jacoco.reuse-data-file=true` to your application.properties. Otherwise Unit test report may get overriden with integration test coverage report data

1. Add the jacoco plugin along with other plugins required.

```
plugins {
  ....
  ....
  id("io.quarkus")
  id("jacoco")
  id("org.sonarqube") version "3.2.0"
}
```

2. Add the quarkus-jacoco extension for tests

```
    dependencies {
     ....
     ....
        // Test Dependencies
        testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5")
        /**
         * The Quarkus automatic JaCoCo config will only work for tests that are annotated with @QuarkusTest.
         * For coverage of other tests we will need to fall back to the JaCoCo maven plugin.
         */
        testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-jacoco")
    }
```

3. Add below config for test tasks

```
    tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true

    finalizedBy(tasks.jacocoTestReport)

    /**
     * Ignore @QuarkusTest related classes, as they will be covered via Quarkus automatic JaCoCo config
     *
     */
    configure<JacocoTaskExtension> {
        excludeClassLoaders = listOf("*QuarkusClassLoader")
        setDestinationFile(layout.buildDirectory.file("jacoco-quarkus.exec").get().asFile)
    }

    /**
     * Set this config to false if you are also using the quarkus-jacoco extension and have at least one @QuarkusTest.
     * The default jacocoTestReport task can be skipped since quarkus-jacoco will generate the combined report of
     * regular unit tests and @QuarkusTest classes since the execution data is recorded in the same file.
     */
    tasks.jacocoTestReport.configure {
        enabled = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ashutosh5111, I believe that what you're mentioning is the guide for unit tests, while the one for integration tests is section 7.1, and for this integration tests section there's no gradle documentation

Comment: Hi @Marco, for gradle it doesn't need those configuration. With the configuration what I have mentioned, just run `./gradlew test` command. This will create the jacoco execution file and coverage reports under build directory. This you can pass to sonarqube.

Comment: the "test" task does not run the integration tests, am I wrong? Aren't those only executed if you run the quarkusIntTest task?

Comment: `test` task does run your integration tests annotated with `@QuarkusTest` and if you have added `testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-jacoco")` extension.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. In this post I was referring to the [quarkus integration tests](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-integration-test), I was probably not very clear on that, sorry